# Number of characters in an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring

I need a way to find the number of characters in an `NSString`. The nature of my app requires many multi char unicode characters, which presents obvious problems for the `length` method on `NSString`.

Copied from Apple's developer website:

```
Length  
Returns the number of Unicode characters in the receiver. 
- (NSUInteger)length  
Return Value The number of Unicode characters in the receiver.
```

I do not want the number of characters per se, but rather the number of characters that you would see if the string were printed out. Some characters I use in the app are numbers and letters with overlines, i.e. 0̄  . In unicode, this is represented with two separate unicode characters, however, when printed, is a single entity. When finding the length of the string, I need characters such as 0̄ to only count as one, not two as it would with the `NSString length` method. Is there a way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi lowa, maybe you can read my answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954525/3051096

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can enumerate the characters in the string with the
`NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` option:

```
NSString *string = @"0̄ ";
__block NSUInteger count = 0;
[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                           options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                        usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                            count++;
                        }];
NSLog(@"%ld %ld", (long)count, (long)[string length]);
// Output: 3 5
```

Both the decomposed character 0̄ and the 
Emoji  (which is also stored as two UTF-16 characters – a so-called "surrogate pair") are counted as one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems like a great and reliable way of doing what I need to do. I'll accept this in a minute

Comment: What does the __block do?

Comment: @Iowa15: `__block` allows you to modify the `count` variable from inside the `^{ ... }` block.

Comment: @Iowa15: `__block` is explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1.

Comment: Probably worth wrapping this up into a category method and sticking it in your standard library (and kind of a shame that Apple hasn't done so).