# NSString length with flag emojis

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, emoji

I'm trying to get the length of an NSString that contains a bunch of emojis, including the flag characters.  Now I know how to get the length of a string containing emojis:

```
__block NSInteger length = 0;
[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:range
                           options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                        usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    length++;
}];
```

However, "NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences" doesn't work in this case.  Normal emojis are composed of two characters put together.  The flag emojis are composed of two emoji-like characters put together.  Thus the length of one flag emoji without any enumeration technique is 4.

How do I get the proper length (number of characters) of an NSString containing flag emojis?

Comment: What's wrong with `NSInteger length = [string length];`?  You can use `substringWithRange` to get just the range you're interested in.

Comment: @Alex Note that when you say the length of a flag character is 4 that is 4 UTF-16 code units or 8 bytes.

Comment: @i_am_jorf @"".length returns 4, is that what you expect for one character? What is the range of the flag character in @" -s-"? Would you expect the range is NSMakeRange(5, 4)?

Comment: Ah I see.  I mentioned range because I saw you were passing in a range to the above.  I'm not sure of the answer, but your example makes your question a lot more clear.

Comment: Unicode in Foundation is just plain broken. A year ago the same could be said for Swift but at least they were honest about length. In Swift 2.0 unified is fixed, yahoo! So, please everyone [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com) and request Apple roll the eSwift unicode change into `NSString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the below solution.
For normal emoji it returns 2 and for flags it will give 4.
Also this will work with normal chars and special chars.

```
const char *cString = [string UTF8String];

int textLength = (int)strlen(cString);
```

Answer (score 2):

**I strongly recommended you read  [This Article](https://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/unicode/)  by [Ole Begemann](https://oleb.net/), which explains NSString/Unicode/Encoding, alone with talking about some pitfalls about NSString length count, comparison, etc.**

According to this article:

You may use:

```
[text lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding] / 4
```

Comment: also according to this article this will not always work 